# Fogged window on Shimano revoshift

Tags: shimano, grip-shifter

Shimano revoshift is fogged so gear number is not readable.  I’ve washed the outside with isopropal to no effect.  How to remove lens and or replace it ?

Comment: A good command of profanity is generally required.

Comment: @DanielRHicks what do you mean? I'm guessing it's a joke/figure of speech of some sort rather than a technical comment but I really don't get it.

Comment: @pateksan - I mean you're going to be cussing a lot when you do this.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to remove, clean and replace the cover. As Carel says, know you can replace the part before disassembly.

The [Dealer's Manual for the REVOSHIFT Shifter](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-SL0002-03-ENG.pdf) seems to indicate the method for removing the cover.
Page 14 tells how to remove the cover.

[image]

Page 15 tells how to put it back on).

[image]

I left step 3 out for brevity. It tells how to remove and replace the cable.

I'd be tempted to leave it alone and shift by feel.

Comment: "I'd be tempted to leave it alone and shift by feel." Agreed -- I've never found it useful to have an indicator of what gear I'm in, even when one has been available. It's easy to remember which chainring you're using and the only time you "need" to be in a specific gear at the back is for starting off. But, whatever gear you like to set off in, it'll probably be one of the biggest two or three on the cassette, and you can find it by changing to the biggest one and then correcting.

Comment: Interesting - that's different to the one I had where the window was in the part fixed to the bars.  There must be several different styles.  +1 for you!

Comment: "I'd be tempted to leave it alone and shift by feel." To make it up the very steep entrance hill into my neighborhood, I have to make a specific sequence of shifts in quick order.  Before I get there I'm using whatever gear feels right.  To know what gear I'm in I have to shift all the way down and count clicks back up to where I was.  It would be easier if I could just read which gear I was in.

Answer (score 1):

The one time I tried to disassemble a revoshift with the intention of saving, it broke some flimsy plastic flange and wouldn't work again.

So the safest thing is to replace the shifter with a trigger shifter or a pod shifter or even a friction shifter lever.

If you're feeling brave, you'll want to remove any grip from the bars. and pull the gear cable right out.   Then undo the little hex bolt holding the whole shifter to the bars - might be a M3 or M4.  At this point the grip-shifter  should slide completely off the bars.

At this point you're looking all around it to identify the clips that hold the unit together, and they're all variable in location.  It should unclip around the axis where the handle bars went through.  This is where mine broke.

Once you can get to the back of the clear window, clean it with IPA or meths.  Do note that the black coating will come off too, potentially making your viewport window much larger.

Reassembly should be a simple clip-together then reverse the order.  Do consider using a new inner cable if you can - they're cheap and the old one may be manky already.

Comment: It might be a good idea to inquire whether a replacement is readily available BEFORE starting disassembly.

Answer (score -1):

You've not mentioned how long it's been like that. If the moisture appeared after a very wet ride then it might dry out reasonably quickly and not come back until another equally wet ride. Stating the obvious is allowed on stack exchange isn't it?